# Eclipse can't resolve own maven builds on jenkins which are not in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, jenkins

Scenario:
Working with eclipse and m2eclipse. Using SVN. Having a CI Jenkins Server, which builds all the own developed dependencies and complete applications, which are using these dependencies.

What I want to do:
I don't want to "check out" every dependency in eclipse which are related to the applications.
Instead I'd like to use the "last stable" builds of the internal dependencies of Jenkins.
They should also be accessed like every external project on the Maven Central Repository.

The internal dependencies are already in the local repository and my workspace, but eclipse gets compilation errors because it can't finde the classes of the depencies.
If I am checking out the project of my SVN, then the compilation errors are resolved.

The remote repository (Jenkins server) is configured in eclipse.
So it's possible to resolve the own developed dependencies.

What I've already tried to do, but was no solution:

- In the Jenkins projects I added maven goals (clean test install), but that didn't work
- Rebuild indexes on remote and local repositories
- Updated the POM on the application projects

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in the pom in repository section is it correctly filled out with a valid URL?

Answer (score 0):

Start via installing a repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva and deploy your build results into them that's it.

Comment: Do I have to change something on my POMs or my m2eclipse settings? Because I can't resolve the dependencies.
I already have installed the Nexus repository manager and added my own projects there.